# Using Django inside Tornado App - Can't Access MySQL Records Created After The Tornado App Starts

Tags: python, mysql, django, websocket, tornado

I have a subclass of tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler. Within that class I have a method that uses the Django ORM to grab a user from a model that subclasses: django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser. The code that grabs the user is as follows:

```
user_model = get_user_model()

try:
    user = user_model.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    return user
except user_model.DoesNotExist:
    return None
```

Note: This works absolutely fine if the user corresponding to the user_id is in the database before the Tornado script starts.

However, if I create a new user after the script starts, the above code always returns None. It's as if the script only has access to a snapshot of the database at the time the script starts. I have even tried running a raw sql query with the exact same results:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM custom_user_table WHERE id = %s", [node_id])
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the django orm from a tornado handler can be tricky; you need some hooks with the request starts and stops since django's middleware isn't running.  Here's something I wrote years ago to do this; I have no idea if it still works: https://gist.github.com/bdarnell/654157.  Looking back at it now, I'm not sure if it's correct for asynchronous requests; I think you'd want to do what's in `prepare/finish` in this gist before and after segment that includes a database call.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ben Darnell's code, all it took was the following:

```
from django.db import connection

if user_id is None:
    return None

try:
    connection.queries = []
    user = user_model.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    connection.close()
    return user
except user_model.DoesNotExist:
    return None
```

Comment: Actually, after some fussing all it took was to add:

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after playing around a bit, all that was needed was to add the single line:

```
django.db.connection.close()
```

To the WebSocketHandler's open method. This forces Django to reestablish the connection on the first db call...